# Switch color of button on click (and revert color of other buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have three buttons, and want to change the color of the button on being selected. As you will see, I am able to change the color on selection, but I need buttonA to return to its original color when buttonB is selected (at which point buttonB should take on the selected color) and so on. Currently each button selected takes on the selected color, but buttons do not return to their original color.

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwqv8/

This is the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('button.account').click(function() {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("account");
      jQuery(this).addClass("btn-success");
   });
});
```

Ideally there will be a default button (buttonA) which has the selected color when the page loads initially.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you don't need the jQuery(document).ready( since the code is executed on a click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove the btn-success class on all buttons in the onclick function, then add the class only to the newly selected

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('button.account').click(function() {
      jQuery('button.btn-success').removeClass('btn-success');
      jQuery(this).removeClass("account");
      jQuery(this).addClass("btn-success");
   });
});
```

Or you could have an array with the currently selected buttons, and removing the btn-success class on a newly clicked button

http://jsfiddle.net/Fwqv8/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $acctButtons = jQuery(".account");
    jQuery('button.account').click(function() {
        $acctButtons.removeClass("btn-success");
        jQuery(this).addClass("btn-success");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN USE `TOGGLECLASS` FOR SINGLE BUTTON

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/Fwqv8/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('button.account').click(function(){
            var that = this;
            jQuery('button.account').each(function(i, btn){
                jQuery(this).addClass("btn-danger");
                jQuery(this).removeClass("btn-success");
            });
            jQuery(that).addClass("btn-success");
        });
     });
```

This code does all your buttons switch back to their default state on click. Only the clicked button will stay (in your case) "green".

An default button can easily been done by setting the default class in your markup.

Comment: Why would you add `account` class to a button that already has that class?
And you don't need the `jQuery(document).ready(` since the code is executed on a click

Comment: @PLAudet Oh I see. The adding of account is not neccessary. Read the question and there was a removal of this class so I my first thought I added the class. And like said before I used `.ready` because in the question there was also the `.ready` function.

Comment: Ho didn't see the Ready in the question :P

Comment: if I take the account class out of the jquery and the html, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: scrub that. It does work. And I dropped the document ready too thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $('.btn').removeClass("btnSelected");
        $(this).addClass("btnSelected");
    })

});
```

CSS

```
.btn{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
}
.btnSelected{
  background-color:green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="btn1" class="btn">Button 1</div>
<div id="btn2" class="btn">Button 2</div>
<div id="btn3" class="btn">Button 3</div>
```

[Try @ codebins](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp4j)