# Issue with jQuery : Click event & Switching between "active" elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

OK, here's my issue and <del>I bet it'll be super-easy for you</del> (I guess it wasn't... lol).

So, let's say I'm having several `div`s. Once the user clicks on one of them, I want to highlight just this one. In a few words : a) remove (if exists) a specific class from all `div`s, b) add it to the `div` being clicked.

And here's the full code...

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html style='min-height:0px;'> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <div data-role="page">


    </div>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**custom.js**

```
$(function() {
    $("div").click( function() {
        $("div").removeClass("msp-selected");
        $(this).addClass("msp-selected");
    });
});
```

**custom.css**

```
media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page {
        min-height: 420px;
    }
}
media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page {
        min-height: 300px;
    }
}

div {
    outline:0;
}

div:hover {
    outline-width:1px;
    outline-color:red;
    outline-style: dotted;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.msp-selected {
    outline-width:1px;
    outline-color:red;
    outline-style: solid;
}
```

---

**P.S.**

- The situation may not be as simple as it initially seemed. I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.2. And the actual page is running inside a Webview, itself inside a Cocoa/OS X app. Quite complicated, huh? lol
- I can't see any error (not easy to have access to a console that... doesn't exist...). The only thing that I noticed is that when I remove the `removeClass` part, it does work. Adding it, seems to make the whole thing a mess.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129040/switch-color-of-button-on-click-and-revert-color-of-other-buttons/

Pretty much the same thing you are trying to do

Comment: What you have should work exactly as you describe, so there must be some other issue. Have you included `jquery.js` in your page?

Comment: work for me http://jsfiddle.net/MLvuq/

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/yVxhK/

Comment: @rps yes, it is, `$() == document.ready()`

Comment: what version of jquery are u using, or are any error's on your console?

Comment: it should work and working as expected. one question, did you notice this on specific browser?

Comment: @NabilKadimi yes, didnt note that correctly!

Comment: I've edited the post, please have a look! :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon nice edit ... lol :)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon u are using jquery-mobile, did u try with `tap` or `vclick`..

Comment: another edit?!! oh this one is understandable by me!

Comment: Hahaha! You guys are funny... :-)

Comment: @RicardoArruda I did, and it didn't work either. Btw, I don't think it may have anything to do with jQuery Mobile touch gestures handling - even though it's based on jQuery Mobile, it's not to be running on a mobile device (so why I'm I using jQuery Mobile you're asking... - makes sense! lol)

Comment: Nah not as funny as you @Dr.Kameleon, after reeling us in with _I bet it'll be super-easy for you_, the _P.S._ was really something, are there any other classes already present in that div?

Comment: @rps LOL. Nope, the `div`s are just the normal ones (yep, there are those too!) used by jQuery Mobile (`<div data-role='page'></div>`, etc)

Comment: FYI, the complete source has been added to the original question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(function() {
 $('div').on( "click", function() {
$(this).addClass('msp-selected');
$(this).siblings().removeClass('msp-selected');
})
```

Comment: Please explain why you think that it solves the problem. Btw, you are assuming that all `div` elements are siblings, which is generally not the case.

Comment: Please post your html code so that the corresponding scrpit can be posted

Comment: You should comment on the question, not on your answer. Otherwise I'm the only that gets notified and it's not my question.

Comment: i don't have reputation to comment on question

Comment: Surprisingly - although dealing just with the `siblings` is not the most "elegant" way - **this** is the way that works...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$(".box").click( function() {
    if($(".activeBox").length > 0) { //check if there is an activeBox element
    $(".activeBox").removeClass("activeBox"); //if there is, remove it
}
    $(this).addClass("activeBox"); //make the clicked div the activeBox
});
```

`.box` and `.activeBox` classes to be replaced by your own inactive and active selectors as you want.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maddest_march_hare/CFRvM/) example

Update:

With the new HTML, I got this working as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cc5Ht/)

Here's the code:

HTML within jsFiddle's existing head/body tags:

```
<div data-role="page">


</div>
```

CSS from OP:

```
div {
    outline:0;
}

div:hover {
    outline-width:1px;
    outline-color:red;
    outline-style: dotted;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.msp-selected {
    outline-width:1px;
    outline-color:red;
    outline-style: solid;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("div").click( function() {
    if($(".msp-selected").length > 0) {
        $(".msp-selected").removeClass("msp-selected");
    }
    $(this).addClass("msp-selected");
});
```

I tested this with the various versions of jQuery available back to 1.7.2 and mobile 1.1.1, with the class being added on click each time. My only suggestion if this still doesn't work is to encase the whole thing in `$(document).ready( function() { //click function });` or switch to `$("div").on("click", function() {});`

Comment: Hmm very odd, I've tried the same jsFiddle example using various mixtures of older jQuery and jQuery Mobile without having it stop working. Are you still trying to use `div` as your selector and could you update the question with some HTML examples too?

Comment: I just updated my answer, let me know if that helps! Otherwise it may be an issue with the environment it's working in, not the code itself